How does TIPS perform during the recent inflation period in the US?
I'm reading The Permanent Portfolio and there's one paragraph talks about TIPS. It claims the TIPS is never put under pressure, and it's like buying fire insurance from an arsonist, quote:

TIPS have only been available in the United States since 1997 and have not been through a period of high inflation. Therefore, anyone stating how TIPS would do during a period of high U.S. inflation is just guessing regardless of what credentials they hold. If the United States were to encounter a period of high inflation, TIPS owners could easily begin to feel more like crash test dummies than investors.
The final word on TIPS is this: Don't buy inflation insurance from the people causing the inflation. Stay away from TIPS and only buy gold for the Permanent Portfolio to guard against inflation.

Since the book is updated around 2011, and the US just ended an inflation period started from  Mar 2022 (it's when the interest rate is increased).
Now I'm wondering whether the statements above still solid? Did TIPS pass the "crash test"?

The earliest recorded inflation-indexed bonds were issued by the Commonwealth of Massachusetts in 1780 during the Revolutionary War and they did work! They are just adjusting the principal value of the security in line with the inflation rate. When CPI rises, the principal value of a TIPS bond also rises.

Short answer: TIPS bond mutual funds performed better than ordinary bond mutual funds of similar duration through the recent inflationary period provided that the TIPS funds were purchased well before inflation started. TIPS performed worse than ordinary bond funds when purchased during high inflation, and significantly worse when purchased before a period of low inflation and sold while inflation remained low.
As happens so often, it depends on the clarity of your crystal ball that makes you decide when to get in and when to get out of TIPS vs ordinary bond funds. I'll give you some examples using Vanguard mutual funds. We'll assume that taxes don't play any role because the funds are in an IRA.
For non-TIPS, I'm using VBILX, an intermediate term bond fund that invests in U.S. Treasuries, U.S. agency bonds and some U.S. investment grade corporate bonds. Its average duration is currently 6.2 years. I'll abbreviate it "IB" for intermediate bond.
For TIPS I'm using VIPSX, a TIPS mutual fund that invests almost exclusively in TIPS. Its average duration is currently 6.7 years, a reasonably close match.
In the early days of the COVID pandemic, there was a so-called "flight to safety" with people buying up Treasury bonds up until about March 5, 2020. If you had bought IB and TIPS just then, you would have been kicking yourself because the next few weeks comprised the March 2020 "dash for cash" when people started realizing that the pandemic would be prolonged and they'd better sell some bonds for cash to ride out the economic storm. The intermediate bond market lost about 7% in a matter of days. If you held fast, and held your two investments until today (October 2024) always reinvesting dividends, the IB would today be worth -3% and the TIPS would be +6%. Good deal, TIPS came through inflation better than IB.
Looking at inflation year-to-year, 2020 was a mere 1.4% and 2021 was 7%. Suppose your long-term strategy had been to include TIPS and intermediate bond in your portfolio all along, and you bought both well before inflation hit. From January 1, 2019 to today, TIPS gained +19% and IB gained 13.5%. Again a good deal through massive inflation.
Suppose the 7% inflation made you panicky in 2021, so on January 1, 2022, amid rampant inflation, you bought both TIPS and IB? Oops, bad deal. From then through today, TIPS lost -5.7% but IB lost only -4.7%.
So these numbers suggest that if you buy TIPS rather than intermediate bond before high inflation and hold them through inflation, it's a good deal. If you buy during high inflation, not so good.
But what happens when there's no significant inflation for a long time? Looking at 2014 through 2019, those five years racked up inflation rates of 0.8%, 0.7%, 2.1%, 2.1% and 1.9%. If you had bought both of these two funds on 1/1/14, reinvested dividends and held them until 1/1/19, the TIPS would have gained +7.5% and the IB would have gained +15.5% during that time. Bad deal!
So what's the answer? Don't buy TIPS unless everything is normal and calm and you're the only one who knows that we're going to have sustained high inflation for the next few years. Why should you be the only one who knows about coming inflation? Because if everybody else knows, TIPS are already overpriced. It's the old Efficient Market Theory spoiling things for you.

When inflation heated up, the yields of TIPS bond funds predictably rose.  However, when the Fed started raising interest rates shortly after, the change in interest rates resulted in the price of TIPS bond funds decreasing.
To maintain their intended duration the TIPS bond funds had to keep buying and selling TIPS throughout high inflation and high interest rates.  Now we've got low inflation with interest rates starting to come down.  This should result in increasing prices for the TIPS bond funds.
Over the past 3 years, the total return for iShares TIP has been -0.75% in nominal dollars.  That's not very good compared to the inflation we've had during the same period.
What about buying and holding TIPS?  Before the pandemic, TIPS were available at zero or slightly negative real interest rates.  However, if you buy and hold TIPS starting today over a large range of maturity dates, you can expect about 1.3% real yield.
I've stopped buying TIP bond funds, but I am considering purchasing a TIPS bond ladder within an inherited IRA to bridge the period from my intended retirement to my planned social security claim at 70.
